# Ruby metaprogramming with method_missing to make a HTML DSL

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, method-missing

I'm learning metaprogramming and am trying to make a little DSL to generate HTML.  The `@result` instance variable is not generating the correct answer because when the `h1` method is called, the `@result` instance variable is reset.  Is there an elegant way to deal with these 'nested' method calls (I know [Ruby doesn't technically have nested methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864191/is-it-possible-to-have-methods-inside-methods)).  Here's my code:

```
class HtmlDsl
  attr_reader :result
  def initialize(&block)
    instance_eval(&block)
  end

  private

  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    tag = name.to_s
    content = args.first
    @result = "<#{tag}>#{block_given? ? instance_eval(&block) : content}</#{tag}>"
  end
end

html = HtmlDsl.new do
  html do
    head do
      title 'yoyo'
    end
    body do
      h1 'hey'
    end
  end
end
p html.result # => "<html><body><h1>hey</h1></body></html>"
# desired result # => "<html><head><title>yoyo</title></head><body><h1>hey</h1></body></html>"
```

Comment: Fyi, if you're interested in using Ruby DSL to generate HTML in a production-grade project, you may want to look at [Erector](https://github.com/erector/erector).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is not that `@result` is reset, only that you add into the `@result` the return value of `instance_eval(&block)`, which is the *last line* in the block, and not the aggregated block. This should work better (although not perfectly):

```
class HtmlDsl
  attr_reader :result
  def initialize(&block)
    instance_eval(&block)
  end

  private

  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    tag = name.to_s
    content = args.first
    (@result ||= '') << "<#{tag}>"
    if block_given?
      instance_eval(&block)
    else
      @result << content
    end
    @result <<  "</#{tag}>"
  end
end
```

So now:

```
html = HtmlDsl.new do
  html do
    head do
      title 'yoyo'
    end
    body do
      h1 'hey'
    end
  end
end
p html.result
#=> "<html><head><title>yoyo</title></head><body><h1>hey</h1></body></html>"
```

What I've done is that each call actually renders a *fragment* to the `@result`, so inner calls render inner fragments, each wrapping its own inner fragments with tags.