# Append to an outer variable in a closure

Tags: ruby, closures

I have the following closure:

```
def func
  def inner_func
    list << 3 # how to append an element to the outer `list`?
  end

  list = []
  inner_func
  list
end
```

I am not sure how I can append something to `list` from `inner_func`, as the above attempt is wrong.

Comment: Problem with Ruby is that it _looks_ like it supports nested methods, but it doesn't, as pointed out by Piotr. You could use eg. Procs though, as indicated in http://www.elonflegenheimer.com/2012/07/08/understanding-ruby-closures.html

Comment: I understand. Get you point how to use procs in my case? Also, `inner_func` is actually a whole lot bigger, is it right to stuff everything inside a proc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use instance methods, like this:

```
def func
  def inner_func
    @list << 3 # how to append an element to the outer `list`?
  end

  @list = []
  inner_func
  @list
end
```

However take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864191/is-it-possible-to-have-methods-inside-methods) - regarding Ruby and nested methods.

Example of a clean workaround:

```
def func
  list = []
  inner_func list # => [3]
  inner_func list # => [3, 3]
end

def inner_func(list)
  list << 3
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Ruby does not have nested methods. It does have lambda's, which happen to be closures.

```
def func
  list = []
  l = ->{ list << 3}
  l.call
  p list
end

func # => [3]
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, my `inner_func` is recursive, how can I use lambdas in that case?

Comment: Lambda's can be recursive:`fac = ->(n){ |n| n==1 ? 1 : n * fac.call(n - 1)}; fac(5).call`