# Ruby define method to return proc which makes use of an argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, proc

In Ruby, I'd like to define a method that takes an argument, which returns a proc full of methods that make use of that argument.  Something like the following

```
def test(word)
  proc do
    def hello
      puts word
    end
  end
end

my_proc = test('hello')
my_proc.call.hello
```

When running this code, the local variable 'word' is undefined

To give some more context, I am trying to make use of [association extensions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions), which allow you to provide a block of methods to an association to define extra helper methods on the association.  I have some methods I'd like to use on several similar active record models with similar associations, but they only differ by a certain symbol when making calls (the name of the join table passed to `through` on a `has_many` relationship).  So ideally I was thinking of making a method that accepts that symbol, which could then be used in the implementation of the association extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example has two problems:

1. You can't call a "proc full of methods" like that -- it'll work as an association extension, but there the block is evaluated as a module body, not `call`ed.
2. The `def` keyword resets the local variable scope. To get a value into a function, you can either define it using `define_method` instead (that block retains surrounding scope), or put the value somewhere else the function will be able to find it (a class variable, for example).

---

```
def test(word)
  proc do
    define_method(:hello) do
      puts word
    end
  end
end

Class.new(&test("hello")).new.hello
```

---

Separately, if you're defining approximately the same method on several associations, there might be a simpler path by defining them as class-level scopes.

Answer (score 0):

This is like your call.

```
def test(word)
  proc do
    define_method :hello do
      puts word
    end
  end
end

my_proc = test('hello world')
my_proc.call.hello
```

Ad it returns `# => hello world`

**Edit:** Picking up the @engineersmnky comment, after that you can simply call `hello`.

You can find more informations about here: [Is it possible to have Methods inside Methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864191/is-it-possible-to-have-methods-inside-methods)

Comment: OP Please note that `hello` is also now a method accessible at a "global level". eg. you can just call `hello` without the `proc` as the receiver

Comment: There proc has no sense.

Comment: @engineersmnky, thank you! I did not know this. I edited the post.

Comment: How does this differ from @matthewd's answer?